# bootstrap grid does not show right on smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm working with bootstrap V3.
i'm trying to use the grid property to make a responsive website

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 backgroundcolor">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 backgroundcolor">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 backgroundcolor">1</div>
  </div>
```

but when i view this code on a smartphone the col-xs-1 does not show on the same line as the others.

if i change the lines to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 backgroundcolor">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 backgroundcolor">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 backgroundcolor">7</div>
  </div>
```

the col-xs-7 is not show on the same line as the col-xs-1 and col-xs-4.
on a large screen there is no problem.

you find my code also on http://www.bootply.com/87060.

Comment: Does anyone know? When you check the example code and switch to a small screen size, the first row doesn't render as it should...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this is connected to your problem, but try

```
<div class="container">
```

in line 2 instead of 
    class="col-xs-12

This would be the right way to use the Bootstrap-grid.

Comment: It's not included in the question, but we have the `.container` class in the main html file. The grid above is in a partial view. Could be a bug in BS 3.0 ?